# Matrix manipulation: Scale by a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrices

I am trying to multiply a Gamma distribution by a Gaussian and the bit that is confusing me is as follows

$$
w \exp \big(-\frac{1}{2} (y- \beta x)^T w \Sigma^{-1}(y-\beta x\big)
$$

Here $w$ is a scalat and $\Sigma$ is a matrix. So, $w \Sigma$ is a scaled matrix. My question is whether I can take this $w$ and move this in front, so something like:

$$
w \exp \big(-\frac{w}{2} (y- \beta x)^T \Sigma^{-1}(y-\beta x\big)
$$

Comment: Yes, you can put the $w$ there.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalars commute with matrices in multiplication, so you can do that.

But I wouldn't use the word "equation" for that expression. I might say "move it to the front (or 'to the left') of the product of matrices".